# Как запустить два экземпляра Skype for Business (Lync)

Tags: skype, microsoft-store

Обычный скайп понимает параметр /secondary, Скайп для бизнеса - нет. Установка двух версий (2013 и 2016) не срабатывает. Устанавливаются без конфликтов, но запущен может быть только один из них.

Есть какая-то возможность запустить на одном компе два экземпляра Lync с разными учетками?

Comment: может быть виртуальная машина поможет ?

Comment: данный вопрос следует закрыть, потому что его следует адресовать в соответствующую техподдержку

Answer (score 2):

Никак, но есть вариант с использованием версий разных годов выпуска Lync в составе Office. Вы можете установить версию (Office 2013 с Lync 2013) и Office 2016 (версия Office 365) на одном компьютере, и у них не будет конфликтов. Соответственно залогиниться в них под разными аккаунтами.

Answer (score 0):

Запускаю один из пакета офис, неважно какого, второй запускаю через метро апликашку Lync скачанную из магазина майкрософт.